# Are there more efficient recognizers for the halting problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, semi-decidability

Define the halting problem as $\{\langle M, w\rangle: \text{$M$ is a TM that halts on $w$}\}$. It is undecidable, but recognizable, with a naive recognizer that simulates $M$ on $w$. In a certain sense, it is a "linear"-time algorithm, not in the length of the input of course, but in the "execution complexity" of $M$ running on $w$.

My question is, is it possible to build a more efficient (deterministic) recognizer that can accepts a halting $\langle M, w\rangle$ in less steps than it takes for $M$ to simulate $w$. It could be in the sense of either asymptotically (e.g. log time) or by a constant fraction (e.g. somehow skipping every other simulation step). If not, is it possible for a nondeterministic recognizer?

My intuition is that the answer is no for either case, since we can build some clever TM $M$ that uses the recursion theorem to do some wacky things to escape any "shortcut prediction" made by the recognizer , but I don't know how to formalize it.

Comment: There is no efficient way to compute the halting problem. But did you mean the problem $\{ \langle M,x,1^t \rangle \mid M \text{ accepts }x\text{ within } t \text{ steps}\}$?